# (XNA) Switching Render Target causes performance hit

Tags: xna, drawing, render, target

I have the following problem. I'm trying to cut parts of the texture using the Stencil, AlphaTestEffect and RenderTarget, but this causes a huge performance hit for me. Without it, I have close to 30fps, while with it, it drops to 4fps.

I was trying to isolate the root of the problem, and while with it, I noticed that even if I do nothing, but switch the active render target to my custom render target, and then right afterwards if I switch it back to backBuffer, my fps drops by close to 10fps's. All I do is this:

```
            graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTargetA);
            graphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
```

While the render target is created that way:

```
        renderTargetA = new RenderTarget2D(KnightGame.CurrentGame.ScreenManager.GraphicsDevice, 800, 480,
                                           false, SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.Depth24Stencil8,
                                           0, RenderTargetUsage.PreserveContents);
```

I tried using DiscardContents, different sizes, but it always drops the fps. I commented all the parts that have to do with cutting off the part of the image and still just with switching the render target it makes a hit to the performance. Can anybody direct me to the cause of this problem?

Lucas

Comment: I'm my engine, I switch render targets about 8 times per frame, and still keep well above several hundred frames per second. I think you'll find the error is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: If you create the render target in the Draw method, you'll have to dispose it.

Comment: "I'm my engine, I switch render targets about 8 times per frame, and still keep well above several hundred frames per second. I think you'll find the error is somewhere else in your code."

Any clues MindWorX?

"If you create the render target in the Draw method, you'll have to dispose it"

I don't. It's created in the constructor of the current level, so outside of the draw method.